# Generate routes from a list of checkins in SQL (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

my table: checkins(userid,time,venueid)

Problem: to generate a view representing "steps" of the routes traveled by an user

Idea: to generate couples of the form (A,B) where A is a checkin and B is the subsequent checkin with time constraints(same day, B comes after  A)

What does not work: right now my query generates query like (A,B1), (A,B2)... where Bx is a checkin that has been done after A. The same is true for (A1,B),(A2,B)... couples.

What i need are only the couples of the form (A,B1) and (A1,B), that represent the real subsequent "steps" in the route, like arcs in a graph where nodes are the original checkins.

Example of my current result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgUjy.png 
The first 3 rows have the same arrival_time while the last 2 have the same starting time. What i need are only the row 1 and 4.

My actual solution: http://pastebin.com/8PTDfM1K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have another condition in the `WHERE` using `NOT EXISTS` and a third query of the same table for a check-in in between (beware of multiple check-ins at the same timestamp!), or use `row_number()` as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_checkins AS
SELECT
    userid,
    time,
    venueid,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time) as row_number
FROM "POIs"."test";
```

Then you can build the join as follows:

```
select A.userid, A."venueID", B."venueID", A.time as start_time, B.time as arrival_time
from vw_checkins as A, vw_checkins as B
where
    B.row_number = A.row_number + 1
    and date_trunc('day', A.time)=date_trunc('day', B.time)
    and A."venueID" <> B."venueID"
    and A.userid=B.userid;
```

Note that I also replaced your `NOT LIKE` with `<>`: `[NOT] LIKE` takes time so drop it if you don't need it (i.e. the regex comparison).