# Postgresql: generate incremental ids in a select

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

i have a table of the form (user, day, from, to). For my definition of route, all the entries with the key (user,day) are in a route. I want to create an id for every route so that

the entries

```
(0001,1970/01/01,A,B),(0001,1970/01/01,B,C),(0001,1970/01/01,C,D)
```

turns into

```
(0001,1970/01/01,A,B,1),(0001,1970/01/01,B,C,1),(0001,1970/01/01,C,D,1)
```

while

```
(0002,1970/01/01,A,B)
```

will turn into

```
(0002,1970/01/01,A,B,2)
```

because it is made by a different user.

Comment: See the following for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683703/generate-routes-from-a-list-of-checkins-in-sql-postgres

Comment: How can you differentiate steps of different routes from each other? If no route_id, can you be sure that no two routes go through the same point? I doubt it.

Comment: That's not my problem. I have my user that goes through n points. I just need to track the route of every single user and identify its path.

Comment: So it is one route per 'user'. That is good to know. (Then `id` is redundant in te second schema.)

Comment: Thinking of the broader application of this problem: is it really impossible to keep the timestamps/counters of these steps? Because it is mathematically possible even without them but a bit more complicated.

Comment: @DanielSparing that's similar because... that's me. But it's in no way the same problem. That was a question to generate the steps (that anyway were generated in a different and more efficient way), now i need to create the routes for every single user. The resulting table of that question is my current table of steps but now i need to make the routes "explicit".

Comment: Alright, but my point here is, you should retain the time or the row_number variable from the earlier tables and your problem is much simpler.

Comment: @DanielSparing i have the timestamps in my steps view but i thought it  wasn't needed. Anyway you are making me think: for my definition of route, there is only a route per user, per day. What i really need is to create an id for every couple (user,day). I'm gonna edit the question right now.

Comment: Edited, take a look now. I think it's simpler and clearer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to use window function in a subquery to get the id for each pair of user+date and then join with that.

```
SELECT
  r.ruser
  ,r.rdate
  ,r.rfrom
  ,r.rto
  ,q.row_n
FROM
  routes AS r
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
          r.ruser
          ,r.rdate         
          ,dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY r.ruser ,r.rdate) AS row_n
        FROM
          routes AS r       
      ) AS q
    ON q.ruser = r.ruser AND q.rdate = r.rdate
ORDER BY
  r.ruser
  ,r.rdate
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06668/2)

Comment: It is good idea to use dense_rank() here. The self join is not necessary, though. Simple query will suffice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e90a0/1.

Comment: @TomaszSiorek I knew it should be possible but I just couldn't get it to work. Please post that as a seperate answer and you have my upvote.

Comment: Or you can edit your query so that I can upvote it for using dense_rank() ;)